# diff returning entire file for identical files

Tags: git, diff

I've got a website that has a git repo. I cloned the repo so that I could develop in one directory and then push to the repo, and then pull in the live/prod directory (would be interested in suggestions for a better way to do this if there is one, but that's outside the scope of this question).

I did the following in the live directory to push all my latest changes:

```
git add .
git commit -a // added a message
git push
```

I then did the following in the dev directory:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:user/repo.git
```

I then opened two files, prod/root/test.php and dev/root/test.php, and they looked identical. However, when I did the following diff command, it outputted the entire file:

```
diff prod/root/test.php dev/root/test.php
```

I am so confused as to why diff would output the entire file if they're identical... I also tried googling this and can't find anyone else with this problem. Maybe it's a line endings issue or a character encoding issue where they look the same but they are actually different and git/bitbucket converts it when you push to their repo? That's the only thing I can think of... Either that or I'm missing something really obvious.

Here's the output:

```
1,3c1,3
< <?
< echo '<p>Hello world!</p>';
< ?>
---
> <?
> echo '<p>Hello world!</p>';
> ?>
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This seems like a whitespace issue, in order to avoid them in the future, you can setup Git to normalize them.

Windows and UNIX system don't use same line-ending, to prevent conflict from happening based on these, you should setup you git config this way:

- **Windows** : `git config --global core.autocrlf true`
- **Unix**    : `git config --global core.autocrlf input`

Next, to make sure we only commit with ideal whitespace rules, you can set this [config option](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration):

```
git config --global core.whitespace trailing-space,space-before-tab,indent-with-non-tab
```

Comment: what is the difference between `input` and 'true`?

Comment: Also can you add an explanation of what this does `git config --global core.whitespace trailing-space,space-before-tab,indent-with-non-tab`?

Comment: @alpha_989 added a link to documentation https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

Answer (score 20):

Most likely it's line termination. Try `git diff --ignore-space-at-eol`. And for plain (not `git`) diff it's `diff -b`.

Answer (score 2):

That usually means the line endings are different. Most diffin programs allow you to ignore differences in line endings. Does yours allow you to do so?

Answer (score 1):

I was just having this issue in a JetBrains IDE and it was because when I saved the file, the IDE was changing the line endings.  I just needed to go to the bottom-right corner and switch the line endings back to their original setting to make the diff look right.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not the solution, will help this to you.

`git diff --no-ext-diff --ignore-space-change -- <path>` -> You can view only the code changes in git bash.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @SimonBoudrias's excellent answer, `git config --global core.autocrlf true` ask's git to convert line endings from LF to CRLF on checkout. Very useful for developers working on Windows. This command will add the following to `%HOMEPATH%\.gitconfig`:

```
[core]
    autocrlf = true
```

Running the command from `Git Bash` is best, but the above lines can be manually added into `.gitconfig` if you find that easier.