# git diff sees whole file as changed when it's not

Tags: git, git-diff

The git diff engine is seeing a whole file as changed when it has not. For example, take this commit: https://github.com/etiago/phpvirtualbox/commit/626e09958384f479f94011ac3b8301bd497aec51

Here we see that the file **lib/vboxconnector.php** has 2807 additions and 2778 deletions. Additionally, from doing a manual git diff I find that indeed, the whole file is taken in as a deletion (marked with minus) and a whole new file is taken as an addition. However, the files have a lot in common which Git simply ignored.

I've looked at [diff returning entire file for identical files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876350/diff-returning-entire-file-for-identical-files) but it does not seem to be the case as no white space changes exist between the two commits.

Furthermore, taking the two commits of the file (the one in `626e09958384f479f94011ac3b8301bd497aec51` and `626e09958384f479f94011ac3b8301bd497aec51^1`) and diff'ing them using Meld, I get the right diff analysis.

I've uploaded the two commits of the file to my Dropbox for convenience: [commit_1](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59728/disposables/vboxconnector.php_1) [commit_2](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59728/disposables/vboxconnector.php_2).

Comment: Or.....  It's correct and you did rewrite the file!

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Huh? It's a serious problem I'm still trying to cope with.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

In `vboxconnector.php_1`, every line is terminated by a `CR` `LF` sequence.

In `vboxconnector.php_2`, every line is terminated by just `LF`.

Thus every line of the file has changed.

Try using `git diff --ignore-space-at-eol`.

You may also find some useful information in [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1889559/77567).

Comment: go to repo and execute this command git config --global core.autocrlf true

Comment: ^^ that worked. Android Studio was already set to CRLF

Comment: You can achieve the same using git UI. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63062580/3361311