# Git Script wording changed to strange syntax after staging changes

Tags: javascript, git

Before staging the change

[image]

After staging the change

[image]

This strange issue causes me big trouble on saving the changes. Git thus always displays everything changed.

I tried to remove and create a new branch, but it doesn't work.
I also tried the ans from:
[Stackoverflow question: diff returning entire file for identical files.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876350/diff-returning-entire-file-for-identical-files)
(Though I am quite sure I didn't use unix to edit this file.)
However, the same situation still occurs.

Any suggestion to fix it?

Comment: This looks like an encoding problem.  Are you using a plain text editor, or is it possible that you pasted some UTF-8 rich text and saved it?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I just use VScode to edit it, with Gitlen. After ur question, I tried to copy and paste all text to another file, and another file don't show the same problem. So now I just use that 'another file' to substitute this one.  However, I am still curious how to solve this, as there may still be other files sharing the same situation, I probably dun want to repeatedly create and replace old file. Thx

Comment: Are these just JS files?  When you save, is there an encoding option?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Just JS files, I dun have any encoding option when I saved. Probably some setting in Git makes this error? Please let me know if I can read those setting somewhere.